# Using shared memory in ArrayFire

Tags: shared-memory, gpgpu, arrayfire

Does anyone know how to declare that an array of data in ArrayFire should be stored in shared memory instead of global memory? Is this possible? I have a small set of data that needs to be randomly accessible by all threads. It's a constant look-up table that should be available for the life of the application. Maybe I am just missing the obvious or something, but reading the ArrayFire docs and googling have not turned up any info on how I tell ArrayFire that my data needs to go into shared memory.

Comment: Shared memory has the lifetime of a kernel, and is local to a block. What you want to use for something like a small, constant lookup table is _constant_ memory. However, I don't think ArrayFire allows you to specify the memory in which an array should reside, honestly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CUDA Shared memory (Local memory in OpenCL) is a very fast type of memory that is located on the GPU. It has the same lifetime as on thread block and can only be accessed by threads in the same thread block. It therefore cannot be used to store persistent data which needs to be used by multiple kernels even in raw CUDA. You might want to look into constant or texture memory to implement a look up table(LUT). These memory types are usually more suited for the type of access you usually encounter with a LUT.

ArrayFire has a high level API which makes GPU programming easy with one of the fastest implementations of many commonly used functions. With ArrayFire you will not be able to specify which type of memory is created but you are free to use the data in your own kernel. If you are using one of our function then it is very likely we will make use of shared/texture/constant memory where it makes sense.

Umar

Disclosure: I am one of the developers of ArrayFire